# Change Navigation Controller item color

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

How can I change the color of `UINavigationController` item?

I use Embed In `UINavigationController` => `UIViewController` and I have by default "< Back". I want to delete this "Back" text and change the color of item to white.

I did try the next:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
}
```

inside of the `UIViewController` inside of which this item appears, but it doesn't help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor` to change the color

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change navigation bar color with following code.

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.greenColor()
```

And change Navigation bar text.

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [UITextAttributeTextColor: UIColor.whiteColor()]
```

**Edited**

To change Text color of bar button

```
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([UITextAttributeTextColor: UIColor.whiteColor()], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```